# How to fill in a single field of an XFA pdf document that is encrypted?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I tested the solution [How to fill a single field of an XFA pdf document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705609/how-to-fill-a-single-field-of-an-xfa-pdf-document/69284559#69284559)
but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.
Can anyone advise me what to do to make it work for the attached pdf?
https://www.podatki.gov.pl/media/6927/pit-4r-12-_v1-0e.pdf

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and where exactly it is going wrong? Also provide the iText version you are using.

Comment: The problem was securing the file from editing.

Comment: I am willing to complete this file using itext 7 core. Unfortunately, I ran into a file flattening issue. I tried to use itext7.pdfxf to flatten it unfortunately it looks like it doesn't work for Net Core.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the code you are trying and describe the problem you are facing?